# Spoj - Mixtures

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, dynamic-programming

Ok this has been driving me crazy. I solved a problem on spoj called MIXTURES (http://www.spoj.com/problems/MIXTURES/). I don't know why i keep getting **segmentation fault**. There is also one catch in the problem that there is **no explicit indicator for end of input**. I think I have handled it correctly but correct me if I am wrong. Here is my code

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

typedef struct temp
{
    int modSum;    //the modular sum of the cluster
    int smoke;     //the minimum smoke that a cluster can give.
}clusterInfo;

int fxDP(int *A,int len)     
{
    int i,j,k,smoke1,smoke2;    
    clusterInfo **dpArr=(clusterInfo **)malloc(sizeof(clusterInfo *)*(len-1));

    for(i=0;i<len-1;i++)
        dpArr[i]=(clusterInfo *)malloc(sizeof(clusterInfo)*(len-i-1));   //len- ( (i+2) -1)= len-i-1
    //dpArr[i] gives info of all clusters of length i+2

    //base case    for clusterLength=2
    for(i=0;i<len-1;i++)
    {           
        dpArr[0][i].modSum=(A[i]+A[i+1])%100;
        dpArr[0][i].smoke=A[i]*A[i+1];
    }
    //endBase Case

    //induction
    for(i=1;i<len-1;i++)   //lengthOfCluster=i+2
    {   
        for(j=0;j<len-i-1;j++)    //len-i-1+i+2-1=len
        {   
            smoke1=(dpArr[i-1][j].modSum*A[j+(i+2)-1]) + dpArr[i-1][j].smoke;
            smoke2=(A[j]*dpArr[i-1][j+1].modSum)       + dpArr[i-1][j+1].smoke;

            dpArr[i][j].smoke=smoke1<smoke2 ? smoke1:smoke2 ;

            dpArr[i][j].modSum=(dpArr[i-1][j].modSum+A[j+(i+2)-1])%100;     
        }   

    }

    int result=dpArr[len-2][0].smoke;
    free(dpArr);
    return result;
}


int main()
{
    int *A; int len,i;
    while(1)
    {   

        scanf("%d",&len);
        if(feof(stdin)) break;      
        A=(int *)malloc(sizeof(int)*len);       
        for(i=0;i<len;i++)
        scanf("%d",&A[i]);

        printf("%d\n",fxDP(A,len)); 
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Just a tip: you can check EOF in your outer loop by typing `while (scanf("%d", &len) != EOF)`, since the `scanf` function _returns the number of items of the argument list successfully filled. This count can match the expected number of items or be less (even zero) due to a matching failure, a reading error, or the reach of the end-of-file._ Source [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/scanf/).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
int result=dpArr[len-2][0].smoke;
```

What happens if len=1 ??

Comment: I would really appreciate if you could accept and upvote my answer if it helped you.